# Changing directory in Git-Bash: using Windows-style directory addresses in MINGW64 on Windows machines

Tags: windows, vim, git-bash

### Question:

`git-bash.exe`, or `MINGW64`, recognizes `cd` commands for directories whose addresses are given in form of: `/Drive_Name/Folder1/Subfolder1`. An example for changing to home dir for a Windows machine users is: `cd /c/users/USERNAME`.

- Is it possible to use the following syntax?

  `cd c:\users\USERNAME`

  Note, the directory address is given in its "native" format: the syntax for which the Windows OS recognizes.
- Alternatively, is there a way to automatically change all the backward slashes into forward slashes when pasting into the Git-bash window?

### Background

I am using `git-bash.exe` on a daily basis: to pull and push to Github, to run `latexmk` for compiling my `*.tex` documents and to SSH my Linux machines. It would be nice to quickly start a `git-bash.exe` process at the desired directory location. And, when on Windows OS, getting addresses in form of `C:\users\USERNAME\project` is the default.

### Assortment of syntax that `git-bash.exe` likes:

- Format 1: the format native to GNU --- `/c/users/USERNAME`;
- Format 2: semi-Windows OS format ==> use forward slash as divider --- `c:/users/USERNAME`;
- Format 3: semi-Windows OS format ==> use TWO backward slashes as divider --- `c:\\users\\USERNAME` (credits: [@VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134133/changing-directory-in-git-bash-using-windows-style-directory-addresses-in-mingw/45136283#45136283))

### Alternatively (pending solutions)

A valid alternative is to have some third-party process to monitor the clipboard, and switch all the backward backward slashes into forward slashes. In my case, this could happen:

1. **[Solved]** In **Vim**, when I use the following mapping to fetch the "parent directory" of the file: `nnoremap <leader><leader>p :let @* = expand("%:p:h")<CR>`

   - Solution: `set shellslash`, see "tentative solution" for more details.
2. Though some clipboard-monitor/recording apps: to simply recognize that the string being assigned to the system clipboard is an address for a folder/directory, and replace all backward slashes to be forward slashes.

Comment: "Is it possible to use the following syntax? `cd c:\users\USERNAME`. Q3 2019, Git 2.23, yes, it is possible. See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45136283/6309)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Tentative solution through *Vim*

In `.vimrc` (or `_vimrc` for Windows), use setting: `set shellslash`, and use the following mapping to copy the addresses:

- Absolute directory to the file:

  `nnoremap <leader><leader>f :let @* = expand("%:p")<CR>`
- Absolute directory to the parent folder:

  `nnoremap <leader><leader>p :let @* = expand("%:p:h")<CR>`
- Ref: [Is it possible to make vim use forward slashes on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464038/is-it-possible-to-make-vim-use-forward-slashes-on-windows)
- Other mappings that are helpful:

  > ```
  > " File Name only, without extension
  > nnoremap <leader><leader>n :let @* = expand("%:t:r")<CR>
  > " Extension.
  > nnoremap <leader><leader>e :let @* = expand("%:t:e")<CR>
  > " Copy the line number with file name
  > nnoremap <leader><leader>l :let @* = expand("%:p").":".line(".")<CR>
  > ```

#### Explanation

What this solution builds on are:

1. `git-bash.exe`'s ability to recognize addresses of the following form: `c:/users/USERNAME/document`, where the *forward slashes* are used as divider.
2. Vim's native function `expand("%:p")` (with other flags) that can copy directory-info to clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution: using **single quotes** does seem to work. Example:

```
cd 'c:\users\USERNAME\Folder_1'
```

Source: [Forward slash vs backward slash for file path in git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396613/forward-slash-vs-backward-slash-for-file-path-in-git-bash)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use the following syntax?

```
cd c:\users\USERNAME
```

I just tried with the latest Git 2.13.3 bash: it works, but I had to type:

```
cd c:\\users\\USERNAME
```

---

2 years later (Q3 2019), you don't even needs to escape the `\`, or to use single or double quotes:

- It does work *without* anything for paths without space in them;
- It works with single or double quotes for paths with spaces in them.

Example:

```sh
vonc@voncav MINGW64 /c/Users
$ git version
git version 2.23.0.windows.1

vonc@voncav MINGW64 /c/Users
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

For paths without space:

```sh
vonc@voncav MINGW64 /d/git
$ cd "c:\Users"

vonc@voncav MINGW64 /c/Users
$ cd 'D:\git'

vonc@voncav MINGW64 /c/Users
$ cd D:\git                      <=========

vonc@voncav MINGW64 /d/git       <=========
```

For paths with spaces:

```sh
vonc@voncav MINGW64 /d/git
$ cd C:\Program Files
bash: cd: too many arguments

vonc@voncav MINGW64 /d/git
$ cd "C:\Program Files"

vonc@voncav MINGW64 /d/git
$ cd 'C:\Program Files'
```

Comment: Exactly, "normal" addresses that comes with a single backward slash ("`\`") in between is not permissible; at minimum as you've demonstrated, we need to use two of them together: the first backward slash serving as the escape character, and the second being the actual directory-divider.